# Magento 2.1 : customer login not working

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, login

I have installed magento 2.1 but when i try to login from front end it redirecting to the same page with this url
`customer/account/login/referer/aHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdC9tYWdlbnRvMjEzYi9jdXN0b21lci9hY2NvdW50L2luZGV4Lw,,/`

i have updated robots.txt with `Disallow: /customer/account/login/referer/`.

[image]

Comment: You use `localhost` as your Top level domain?

Comment: Yes, I have used localhost

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh what you suggest, i have other magento installation on localhost but all are working fine.

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh thanks, changed localhost to 127.0.0.1 and it's working.

Comment: Yes, I think it's the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help @KhoaTruongDinh have posted the answer here for same

Answer (score 1):

I had changed a line `Listen 80` to `Listen 127.0.0.1:80` from `C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf`. Then login is worked.

Comment: https://austin.passy.co/2012/setting-up-virtual-hosts-wordpress-multisite-with-xampp-on-windows-7/